# How to get a particular key from response map

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Calling JPA repository:

```
map.put("data",personRepository.findByPersonId(userList.get(0).longValue()));
```

The response map from the database is:

```
{data=User [personId=23334, emailId=abc2@apple.com, firstName=Jack]}
```

My DTO :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {
    private Long personId;
    private String emailId;
    private String firstName;
}
```

This is what I tried to get the email from the response but was null

```
usersEmailId = (String) map.get("emailId");
```

What is wrong in my code to get a key from response map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usersEmailId = (String) map.get("emailId");

this line won't give you what you require as map only has one key which is by name "data", so you need to first map the value of "data" to your pojo Person and then only you can have your emailId. Basically value of the key "data" is object which should be mapped/parsed before use.

Comment: Hi Vishal, can you share me some pointers or reference on how to do that ?

Comment: you can use jackson api and map your "data" to your pojo like below: final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // jackson's objectmapper
final MyPojo pojo = mapper.convertValue(map, MyPojo.class); your pojo class's variable must have same name as per the map value variable

Comment: Use like final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();                                 // jackson's objectmapper
final Person pojo = mapper.convertValue(map.get("data"), Person.class);

Comment: I created a PersonDTO and tried the conversion but got below, looks its looking for something as "data" :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field "data" (Class com.apple.sre.bolt.dto.PersonDTO), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.apple.sre.bolt.dto.PersonDTO["data"])
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2502) ~[jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar:1.9.10]    My Person DTO has :  public class PersonDTO {

    private Long prsId;
 private String email;
    private String firstName;

Comment: @vicky have you tried above piece of code. You will get desired output.

Comment: Yes I tried this as well as Model Mapper, below is the code as per your recommendation that's giving error     :      final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
          map.put("data",personRepository.findByPrsId(userList.get(0).longValue()));
                        final PersonDTO personDTO = mapper.convertValue(map, PersonDTO.class);
            usersEmailId = personDTO.getEmail();

Comment: you need to use map.get("data") instead of map in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vishal for your help !